# Apache Rewritemap not being read?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a simple key value map file which converts olduserid's to new userid's

The objective is to pullup a member profile page from the old site and redirect to tyhe newsite where the member has a new userid.

My virtualhost config file is like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
ServerAlias *.example.com
DocumentRoot /home/example/www
AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode

        <Directory /home/example/www>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                Require all granted
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>

        CustomLog /var/log/httpd/example.com-access.log combined
        ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/example.com-error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel error

        RewriteEngine on

           RewriteMap profiles "txt:/home/example/www/userMap.txt"

           RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =*.example.com [OR]
           RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com [OR]
           RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com
           RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]`
```

The in root directory my .htaccess looks like this

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$ RewriteRule ^member/([0-9])+$ https://www.newxample.com/member/$%7Bprofiles:$1%7D" [NC,L]
```

The mapfile looks like this but larger

```
5 1
3583 7657
3584 7658
3585 703
```

The permissions for the map file and it's location are 777

I have tried so many ways to write the rules and condition but am getting nowhere.

The redirect works but it does not include the values of the newuseris. It's simply null empty nada!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The `.htaccess` file you've posted is not valid as written, can you please check the formatting and encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr** I'm guessing you haven't defined the rewrite map (and possibly other config) in the `<VirtualHost *:443>` (HTTPS) container AND/OR you are only capturing the first digit of the old user ID.

The virtualhost config you've posted is for port 80 (HTTP) only. Which is redirected to HTTPS (port 443). There's not much point defining the `RewriteMap` in `<VirtualHost *:80>`, since you will also need to define it again in `<VirtualHost *:443>`. The same applies to granting access and allowing `.htaccess` overrides etc.

Basically, the vHost:80 container really just serves to redirect to HTTPS, then most of the config is defined in vHost:443.

Since you are redirecting to HTTPS directly in the vHost container, the `.htaccess` file is only going to be processed (if at all) when the request is already over HTTPS.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$ RewriteRule ^member/([0-9])+$ https://www.newxample.com/member/$%7Bprofiles:$1%7D" [NC,L]
> ```

The formatting/encoding of the code dump in your question is messed up (I'm assuming this is just a formatting issue with your question and not in your actual code), however, your regex that is capturing the old user ID is only capturing the first digit, so the lookup will likely fail (or return the wrong result):

```
^member/([0-9])+$
```

Should be:

```
^member/([0-9]+)$
```

Or, use a shorthand character class, eg. `^member/(\d+)$`

---

*Aside:*

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =*.example.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
```

By default, `SERVER_NAME` is the same as `HTTP_HOST`, ie. the value of the `Host` header used in the request. This is what you would seem to be assuming here, however, it is never equal to `*.example.com` (which is simply a wildcard *alias*). There shouldn't be a need to check the requested `Host` here since for the request to be at this point in the config, it must have already passed the `ServerName` / `ServerAlias` check. (This is assuming this is not the "default" vHost.)

The three `RewriteCond` directives are therefore redundant.

Comment: What a catch. Yes on the 443, completely overlooked that. and the + sign for regex in the wrong location didn't help. Thanks for looking. That was it.!