# Redirect to new URL having looked up new "ID" in RewriteMap which appears in two places in the target URL

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

This one may have been answered but I can't seem to find one that fits my specifics. So apologies if it sounds old.

My rewrite consists of using a rewrite map and a redirect to another domain.

For example:

An old site has moved and new id's have been generated along with file name changes

So this URL:

```
https://www.example.com/gallery/951/med_U951I1424251158.SEQ.0.jpg
```

would need to be redirected to

```
https://www.example2.com/gallery/5710/med_U5710I1424251158.SEQ.0.jpg
```

The new value `5710` comes from a rewrite map lookup where I pass `951`

there are two changes needed and the 2nd change has two possible variations:

1. The first change is `gallery/951` to `gallery/5710`
2. The 2nd change is the filename where the *id* can be delimited in either of 2 ways:

   - `U951I` - delimited between a `U` and an `I`

   or

   - `U951.` - delimited between a `U` and a `.`

I started with something like this:

```
RewriteRule "^gallery/(\d+)/(\s+)$"
```

But that is as far as I can get.

Comment: "between a `U` and an `I` or between a `U` and a `.`" - Would it be safe to assume it is a numeric sequence after the `U`? After the first `U`? Is the filename otherwise entirely variable? Or does it always start `med_U`? Always `.jpg`? Always `.SEQ.0.jpg`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like the following:

```
RewriteCond ${MapName:$1|XXX} (.+)
RewriteRule ^/?gallery/(\d+)/(.*U)\1([I.][^/]+)$ https://www.example2.com/gallery/%1/$2%1$3 [R=302,L]
```

I'm assuming the domain being redirected to resides on a different server, otherwise ([if this is in `.htaccess`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75416533/369434)) you would need to check the requested hostname in an additional *condition* (`RewriteCond` directive).

Explanation:

1. The regex `^/?gallery/(\d+)/(.*U)\1([I.][^/]+)$` matches and *captures* the relevant parts of the source URL...

   - `^/?gallery/` - Literal text (optional slash prefix if this is being used in a *server* context, as opposed to `.htaccess`)
   - `(\d+)` - Captures the "old" member ID (later available using the `$1` backreference and used to lookup the "new" member ID from the `RewriteMap`)
   - `/` - literal slash
   - `(.*U)` - Captures the first part of the filename before the "old" member ID. Later available in the `$2` backreference.
   - `\1` - An internal backreference matches the "old" member ID that occurred in the 2nd path segment - Not captured.
   - `([I.][^/]+)$` - Captures the last part of the filename *after* the "old" member ID - Later available in the `$3` backreference. The character classs `[I.]` matches either an `I` or a literal `.` (the dot does not need to be escaped when used inside a character class). And `[^/]+` matches everything thereafter to the end of the filename (URL-path).
2. The `RewriteCond` directive serves to lookup the new member ID (using the old member ID saved in the `$1` backreference) in the rewrite map defined earlier in the server config. The result is then captured, which is later available in the `%1` backreference. I set a default `XXX` so it would be easy to spot any lookups that fail.

   Using the `RewriteCond` directive means we only lookup the rewrite map once. (Results are probably cached anyway, but it saves repetition at the very least.)
3. `/%1/$2%1$3` - The *substitution* string is then constructed from the backreferences captured earlier:

   - `%1` is the new member ID (captured in the preceding *CondPattern*)
   - `$2` is the part of the filename *before* the member ID (captured by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* against the URL-path).
   - `$3` is the part of the filename *after* the member ID.

Note that backreferences of the form `$n` refer to captured groups in the `RewriteRule` *pattern* and backreferences of the form `%n` refer to captured groups in the last matched *CondPattern* (`RewriteCond` directive).

Comment: OMG! I never would have figured this out . This is awesome and the explanation is so helpful. Thanks !!!